# Mongodb - logical operators e.g. "$lt" "$lte" - but is there one for '=' to simplify programming

Tags: php, mongodb

Jimmy Sawczuk gave a great help going forward, but also inspired me to look into "$in" for using it as an equal '=' operator, but it might not be possible...

I have this code which I would like to make more nice (know it looks complicated (so skip it) but I will get to the point soon and then it might not be that complicated:

```
// First html drop down selection / filter selection
if ($key[0] <> "") {
   if ($op[0] == "=") $query = array($key[0] => $val[0]);
   else $query = array( $key[0] => array( $op[0] => $val[0] ) );
}   
else return($query);
// Second html drop down selection / filter selection
if ($key[1] <> "") {
   if ($op[1] == "=")  $query = array( $log[0] => array( array($key[1] => $val[1]), $query));
   else $query = array( $log[0] => array( array( $key[1] => array( $op[1] => $val[1] ) ), $query) );
}   
else return($query);
```

What I would like to do is to simplify the code (for simplicity I have merged key0 and key1 lines):

```
if ($key[1] <> "")  $query = array( $log[0] => array( array( $key[1] => array( $op[1] => $val[1] ) ), array( $key[0] => array( $op[0] => $val[0] ) )) );

$log: logical operater: "$and", "$or"
$key: key in database
$val: value to be matched against
$op:  operater e.g. "$lt", "$gt", "$lte", "$gte", "$ne" all supported by Mongo.
```

Now my problem is that I would like to have a $op which was '$=' or a bit like $in. However $in seems to match the same key for several values, but in my case the keys could be different. Having a '$=' like operator in mongo would highly simplify my programming. I have read several tutorials but can not find such a operator. I find it is strange as when you have $ne (not equal) why then not having equal. Have I missed something, is there a workaround (well I do workaround now but it looks ugly) or does $= exist ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `equal` operator. Instead, MongoDB simple uses the javascript colon as an equal operator.

So `{x : 1}` means `x equals 1`. In PHP this would translate `array('x' => 1)`.

> I find it is strange as when you have $ne (not equal) why then not having equal.

Yes, it is definitely weird. In fact, it's a [long outstanding bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1367).

A similar problem existed with `$and`. In versions prior to 2.0, there was no `$and` operator. Instead you used the comma `{x:1, y:2}` meant `x equals 1 and y equals 2`. This actually made certain queries with $and/$or combinations very difficult.

Long term, I don't expect that bug to ever be fixed. It will likely all be supplanted by the [new aggregation framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework) which actually supports an `$eq` operator.

Answer (score 0):

As a small note, if you really need to emulate an `$eq`, you can either use:

`{x: {$in: [1] } }`

Or, if you want to avoid `$in` for whatever reason, this also works:

`{x: {$gte: 1, $lte: 1} }`

Any value that is both greater than or equal **and** less than or equal to another value must equal the other value. This works fine with strings:

`{x: {$gte: 'James Bond', $lte: 'James Bond' } }`

It will not work with arrays or objects.

Answer (score 0):

Equality operator `$eq` was introduced in MongoDB 3.0.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/